# relation of kernel in commutative diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

[image: triangle]

Suppose $A,B,C$ are modules in above commutative diagram, $f$ is surjective. I read that $\ker h / \ker f \simeq \ker g$. I proved it after some diagram chasing. ($f$ induces a surjective map $f': \ker h \to \ker g$, so that $\ker g \simeq \ker h/\ker f' = \ker h / \ker f$.) But is there any way to understand it easily? I needed some time to consider details, but I guess it may be easier.

**Edit** I'm sorry that the exactness was not assumed. I deleted it.

Comment: I'm lost here, if $B\to A \to C$ is exact (at $A$, i suppose) and $f$ is surjective, then $A=im(f)=\ker(g)$, so $g$ should be identically $0$, right? On the other hand, since the diagram is commutative, $h = g \circ f = 0$, so $\ker(h) = B$. So your isomorphism is, in this case, just the first isomorphism theorem for $f:A \to B$. (maybe it works even when $f$ is not surjective...)

Comment: @ViniciusM. Sorry that the exactness was unnecessary.

Comment: What is the question? You have given the proof, it is very very easy. What else?